# How to create new generic items for a List<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, refactoring

Given a list of a possible 5 items, the method below will return a new list of exactly 5 items (adding more items if the original list has less than 5).  This works fine, but now I need to refactor it so that it can handle a generic T list (one that will have the same properties of year and Cnt).  How can I convert this method to take in a List and have it return a new List with 5 elements?

```
    private static List<FiveYearComplex> CreateFiveYearTemplate(int startYear, 
        int endYear, ObjectResult<FiveYearComplex> result)
    {
        var list = new List<FiveYearComplex>(5);

        for (int year = startYear; year < endYear; ++year)
        {
            list.Add(new FiveYearComplex() { Year = year, Cnt = 0 });
        }
        FiveYearComplex tmpItem;
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            tmpItem = list.Find(w => w.Year == item.Year);
            if (tmpItem == null)
            {
                tmpItem = new FiveYearComplex() { Cnt = 0, Year = item.Year };
            }
            else
            {
                tmpItem.Cnt = item.Cnt;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

When I try to use List I eventually run into this section:

```
for (int year = startYear; year < endYear; ++year)
{
    list.Add(new T() { Year = year, Cnt = 0 });
}
```

and I get an error...

Thanks!

For completeness:

```
    public interface IYearTemplate
    {
        int? Year { get; set; }
        decimal? Cnt { get; set; }
    }

    private static List<T> CreateFiveYearTemplate <T> (
        int startYear, int endYear, 
        ObjectResult<FiveYearAttendanceComplex> result) 
        where T : IYearTemplate, new()
    {
        var list = new List<T>(5);

        for (int year = startYear; year < endYear; ++year)
        {
            list.Add(new T() { Year = year, Cnt = 0 });
        }
        T tmpItem;
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            tmpItem = list.Find(w => w.Year == item.Year);
            if (tmpItem == null)
            {
                tmpItem = new T() { Cnt = 0, Year = item.Year };
            }
            else
            {
                tmpItem.Cnt = item.Cnt;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Thanks you.

Comment: You almost answered it with a <T> and just return another <T>

Comment: but when I try to do new T() {  Year = year... I get an error...

Comment: You do realize that the number of items in your list is based on the values of `startYear` and `endYear`, and not on the fact that you initialize the list with a capacity of 5 right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot easily convert your method to handle a generic list, because well your method is not generic. It requires for each item in the list to have properties `Cnt` and `Year`, for your method to be generic you have to add this constraint.

```
public interface IYearTemplate
{
   int Cnt {get;set;}
   int Year {get;set;}
}
```

Also your method requires a default constructor, which is expressed as the constraint `new()` - so it could look like this:

```
private static List<T> CreateFiveYearTemplate<T>(int startYear,
    int endYear, ObjectResult<T> result) where T: IYearTemplate, new()
{
    var list = new List<T>(5);

    for (int year = startYear; year < endYear; ++year)
    {
        list.Add(new T() { Year = year, Cnt = 0 });
    }
    T tmpItem;
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        tmpItem = list.Find(w => w.Year == item.Year);
        if (tmpItem == null)
        {
            tmpItem = new T() { Cnt = 0, Year = item.Year };
        }
        else
        {
            tmpItem.Cnt = item.Cnt;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Having said that this method doesn't look very generic, since the constraints are *very specific*. Why do you *want to* make it generic?

Comment: Well I removed all domain vocabulary from this example to keep it simple, but I will have several entities that will need to return a list with 5 years and 5 values (cnt).

Comment: I'm still not sure on your requirements - so are you dealing with different types of lists or are they all returning `List<FiveYearComplex>` - if the later is the case you don't need generics.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.  Generics are so useful!  I def. need to get more familiar with it.

Comment: I'm dealing with several different types of lists like: FiveYearCarComplex, FiveYearTruckComplex, FiveYearSUVComplex. Complex refers to Complex type created from a stored procedure import with the entity framework **phew**

Answer (score 3):

For that to work for arbitrary `T`, you had two choices:

- add a `where T : SomeType` constraint, where `SomeType` is either a base-class or (more likely and more versatile) an interface that declares the properties you need
- switch to using `dynamic` (or reflection before 4.0) to access the properties

The first gives you compile-time safety, but requires some commonality between the `T`; the second demands no commonality, but is entirely runtime - no static-analysis checking.

For example:

```
interface IRenameThis {
    int Year {get;set;}
    int Cnt {get;set;}
}
```

And add `where T : IRenameThis` to the method signature (between te closing `)` of the parameters and te opening `{` of the method body)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I couldn't get it working without using new

Comment: @whatever - oh, right - you'll need `where T : IRenameThis, new()` then - note the `new()`

Answer (score 1):

```
static List<T> CreateFiveYearTemplate( int startYear 
                                      ,int endYear
                                      ,ObjectResult<T> result)
      where T : FiveYearComplex, new()
{
  ...
}
```